# can the value.var in dcast be a list or have multiple value variables?

Tags: r, data.table, reshape, reshape2

In the help files for `dcast.data.table`, there is a note stating that a new feature has been implemented: "dcast.data.table allows value.var column to be of type list"

I take this to mean that one can have multiple value variables within a list, i.e. in this format:

```
dcast.data.table(dt, x1~x2, value.var=list('var1','var2','var3'))
```

But we get an error: `'value.var' must be a character vector of length 1.`

Is there such a feature, and if not, what would be other one-liner alternatives?

**EDIT: In reply to the comments below**

There are situations where you have multiple variables that you want to treat as the `value.var`. Imagine for example that x2 consists of 3 different weeks, and you have 2 value variables such as salt and sugar consumption and you want to cast those variables across the different weeks. Sure, you can 'melt' the 2 value variables into a single column, but why do something using two functions, when you can do it in one function like `reshape` does?

(Note: I've also noticed that `reshape` cannot treat multiple variables as the time variable as `dcast` does.)

So my point is that I don't understand why these functions don't allow for the flexibility to include multiple variables within the `value.var` or the `time.var` just as we allow for multiple variables for the `id.var`.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the documentation. A data.table column can be of type list and such a column can now be the `value.var` column.

Comment: @Arun, I'm not entirely sure how this would be a great improvement (or maybe I don't understand the question correctly). Doesn't the fact that there are multiple `value.var`s imply that the data is not fully "molten"? Alex: Can you update your question to move out of the hypothetical realm and give an example of what you might want to do with these multiple `value.var`s? Maybe you are thinking something like what I did at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15528729/1270695)?

Comment: @Arun I've elaborated on the purpose of this post and my inquiry.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247078/reshape-multiple-values-at-once-in-r

Comment: Related: [Convert data from long format to wide format with multiple measure columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589693/convert-data-from-long-format-to-wide-format-with-multiple-measure-columns)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

From v1.9.6 of data.table, we can cast multiple `value.var` columns simultaneously (and also use multiple aggregation functions in `fun.aggregate`). Please see `?dcast` and the [Efficient reshaping using data.tables](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) vignette for more.

Here's how we could use `dcast`:

```
dcast(setDT(mydf), x1 ~ x2, value.var=c("salt", "sugar"))
#    x1 salt_1 salt_2 salt_3 sugar_1 sugar_2 sugar_3
# 1:  1      3      4      6       1       2       2
# 2:  2     10      3      9       5       3       6
# 3:  3     10      7      7       4       6       7
```

Answer (score 12):

#### Update

Apparently, [the fix was much easier](https://github.com/hadley/reshape/commit/55cc15996c650e5b1019c053fb1409df38fdbf58#diff-9f47e2c152ad92ad85375c027dc96cce)...

---

Technically, your statement that "apparently there is no such feature" isn't *quite* correct. There is such a feature in the `recast` function (which sort of hides the melting and casting process), but it seems like Hadley forgot to finish the function or something: the function returns a `list` of the relevant parts of your operation.

Here's a minimal example...

Some sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(x1 = rep(1:3, each = 3),
                   x2 = rep(1:3, 3),
                   salt = sample(10, 9, TRUE),
                   sugar = sample(7, 9, TRUE))

mydf
#   x1 x2 salt sugar
# 1  1  1    3     1
# 2  1  2    4     2
# 3  1  3    6     2
# 4  2  1   10     5
# 5  2  2    3     3
# 6  2  3    9     6
# 7  3  1   10     4
# 8  3  2    7     6
# 9  3  3    7     7
```

The effect you seem to be trying to achieve:

```
reshape(mydf, idvar='x1', timevar='x2', direction='wide')
#   x1 salt.1 sugar.1 salt.2 sugar.2 salt.3 sugar.3
# 1  1      3       1      4       2      6       2
# 4  2     10       5      3       3      9       6
# 7  3     10       4      7       6      7       7
```

`recast` in action. (Note that the values are all what we would expect in the dimensions we would expect it.)

```
library(reshape2)
out <- recast(mydf, x1 ~ x2 + variable, measure.var = c("salt", "sugar"))
### recast(mydf, x1 ~ x2 + variable, id.var = c("x1", "x2"))
out
# $data
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    3    1    4    2    6    2
# [2,]   10    5    3    3    9    6
# [3,]   10    4    7    6    7    7
# 
# $labels
# $labels[[1]]
#   x1
# 1  1
# 2  2
# 3  3
# 
# $labels[[2]]
#   x2 variable
# 1  1     salt
# 2  1    sugar
# 3  2     salt
# 4  2    sugar
# 5  3     salt
# 6  3    sugar
```

I'm honestly not sure if this was an incomplete function, or if it is a helper function to another function.

All of the information is there to be able to put the data back together again, making it easy to write a function like this:

```
recast2 <- function(...) {
  inList <- recast(...)
  setNames(cbind(inList[[2]][[1]], inList[[1]]),
           c(names(inList[[2]][[1]]), 
             do.call(paste, c(rev(inList[[2]][[2]]), sep = "_"))))
}
recast2(mydf, x1 ~ x2 + variable, measure.var = c("salt", "sugar"))
#   x1 salt_1 sugar_1 salt_2 sugar_2 salt_3 sugar_3
# 1  1      3       1      4       2      6       2
# 2  2     10       5      3       3      9       6
# 3  3     10       4      7       6      7       7
```

Again, a possible advantage with the `recast2` approach is the ability to aggregate as well as reshape in the same step.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to go through this. I wasnt aware of recast which seems to do melt+cast. I'd like to add that `recast` in the reshape package (but not reshape2) is complete and accomplishes the same as your recast2 function.

Comment: @AlexR, see my update at the top of the post. Apparently, all that was needed was a change from `cast` to `dcast` in the `recast` code.

Answer (score 11):

Using sample data frame `mydf` from [A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23161231/2641825).

## Edit December 2016 using `tidyr`

Reshape2 has been replaced with the [tidyr package](ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).

```
library(tidyr)
mydf  %>% 
    gather(variable, value, -x1, -x2)  %>% 
    unite(x2_variable, x2, variable)  %>% 
    spread(x2_variable, value)

#   x1 1_salt 1_sugar 2_salt 2_sugar 3_salt 3_sugar
# 1  1      3       1      4       2      6       2
# 2  2     10       5      3       3      9       6
# 3  3     10       4      7       6      7       7
```

## Original answer based on `reshape2`

@AlexR added to his question:

> Sure, you can 'melt' the 2 value variables into a single column,

For those who come here looking for an answer based on [reshape2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape2/index.html), here is how to melt the data and then use dcast based on the "variable". .

```
dt2 <- melt(mydf, id = c("x1", "x2"))
```

The variable column will now contain 'var1','var2','var3'. You can achieve the desired effect with

```
dt3 <- dcast(dt2, x1 ~ x2 + variable, value.var="value")
dt3
#   x1 1_salt 1_sugar 2_salt 2_sugar 3_salt 3_sugar
# 1  1      3       1      4       2      6       2
# 2  2     10       5      3       3      9       6
# 3  3     10       4      7       6      7       7
```

value.var is optional in this function call as dcast will automatically guess it.

Comment: The Dec 2016 update is in my opinion the most flexible approach now. +1

Comment: And now `gather` and `spread` have been superseded by `pivot_wider` and `pivot_longer` in [tidyr](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2019/09/tidyr-1-0-0/).