# R using Reshape2 to do what reshape (stats package function) was designed for

Tags: r, data.table, reshape2, melt

I'm trying to do exactly what reshape from the stats package is designed for.  I have a wide dataset with a series of variables in the form `var_name.date`.  Unfortunately, reshape seems ill-equipped to deal with even medium-sized datasets, so I'm trying to use the the `data.table.melt` function.

My main problem is grouping the variables into separate value columns based on their long-form variable.  Is this possible, or do I need to do each one separately and then `cbind` them?

Here is what I have:

```
widetable = data.table("id"=1:5,"A.2012-10"=runif(5),"A.2012-11"=runif(5),
                       "B.2012-10"=runif(5),"B.2012-11"=runif(5))


   id  A.2012-10 A.2012-11  B.2012-10 B.2012-11
1:  1 0.82982349 0.2257782 0.46390924 0.4448248
2:  2 0.46136746 0.2184797 0.05640388 0.4772663
3:  3 0.61723234 0.3950625 0.03252784 0.4006974
4:  4 0.19963437 0.7028052 0.06811452 0.3096969
5:  5 0.09575389 0.5510507 0.76059610 0.8630222
```

And here is the the `stats` package's `reshape` mocking me with one-line awesomeness doing exactly what I want but not scaling.

```
reshape(widetable, idvar="id", varying=colnames(widetable)[2:5],
        sep=".", direction="long")


    id  time          A          B
 1:  1 2012-10 0.82982349 0.46390924
 2:  2 2012-10 0.46136746 0.05640388
 3:  3 2012-10 0.61723234 0.03252784
 4:  4 2012-10 0.19963437 0.06811452
 5:  5 2012-10 0.09575389 0.76059610
 6:  1 2012-11 0.22577823 0.44482478
 7:  2 2012-11 0.21847969 0.47726629
 8:  3 2012-11 0.39506249 0.40069737
 9:  4 2012-11 0.70280519 0.30969695
10:  5 2012-11 0.55105075 0.86302220
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just one of those times when `reshape()` is more straightforward to use.

The most direct approach using a combination of `melt` and `dcast.data.table` that I can think of is as follows:

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)

longtable <- melt(widetable, id.vars = "id")
vars <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(longtable$variable), ".", TRUE))
dcast.data.table(longtable[, c("V1", "V2") := lapply(1:2, function(x) vars[, x])],
                 id + V2 ~ V1, value.var = "value")
```

---

An alternative is to use `merged.stack` from [my "splitstackshape" package](https://github.com/mrdwab/splitstackshape), specifically the development version.

```
# library(devtools)
# install_github("splitstackshape", "mrdwab", ref = "devel")
library(splitstackshape)

merged.stack(widetable, id.vars = "id", var.stubs = c("A", "B"), sep = "\\.")
#     id .time_1          A         B
#  1:  1 2012-10 0.26550866 0.2059746
#  2:  1 2012-11 0.89838968 0.4976992
#  3:  2 2012-10 0.37212390 0.1765568
#  4:  2 2012-11 0.94467527 0.7176185
#  5:  3 2012-10 0.57285336 0.6870228
#  6:  3 2012-11 0.66079779 0.9919061
#  7:  4 2012-10 0.90820779 0.3841037
#  8:  4 2012-11 0.62911404 0.3800352
#  9:  5 2012-10 0.20168193 0.7698414
# 10:  5 2012-11 0.06178627 0.7774452
```

The `merged.stack` function works differently from a simple `melt` because it starts by "stacking" different groups of columns in a `list` and then merging them together. This allows the function to:

1. Work with column groups where each column group might be of a different type (character, numeric, and so on).
2. Work with "unbalanced" column groups (where one group might have two measure columns and another might have three).

---

This answer is based on the following sample data:

```
set.seed(1) # Please use `set.seed()` when sharing an example with random numbers
widetable = data.table("id"=1:5,"A.2012-10"=runif(5),"A.2012-11"=runif(5),
                       "B.2012-10"=runif(5),"B.2012-11"=runif(5))
```

---

See also: [What reshaping problems can melt/cast not solve in a single step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675031/what-reshaping-problems-can-melt-cast-not-solve-in-a-single-step)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and for confirming that what I want cannot be done as simply using melt as it can be done using melt. I've been trying with your package using merge.stack but I think I have to resign to doing it piecemeal. For reference, the table has ~150k rows(ids) and 555 variables -- 38 * 14 time periods + some others that aren't related to time. It's about 450mb and I'm working with 8GB RAM and 8GB virtual memory, but both your `merge.stack` and `reshape` exceed my memory capacity.

Comment: @user3747260, Just curious: if you load the data as a "data.table", what size does `tables()` report?